# What is gcc doing here to run this code once per thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading, gcc, assembly, thread-local-storage

I just ran across this technique for running code once per thread. I don't know how it works at the lowest level though. Especially, what's `fs` pointing to? What does `.zero 8` mean? Is there a reason the identifier is `@tpoff`?

```
int foo();

void bar()
{
    thread_local static auto _ = foo();
}
```

Output (with -O2):

```
bar():
        cmp     BYTE PTR fs:guard variable for bar()::_@tpoff, 0
        je      .L8
        ret
.L8:
        sub     rsp, 8
        call    foo()
        mov     BYTE PTR fs:guard variable for bar()::_@tpoff, 1
        add     rsp, 8
        ret
guard variable for bar()::_:
        .zero   8
```

Comment: It just seems that GCC is using a per-thread variable to keep track of the state of `_`. If already set, it doesn't initialise it once more.

Comment: In addition to what Peter Cordes said about not using `_` as variable name, I would also recommend not using `main` in examples meant to show what assembly code the compiler generates. The function `main` is special in many ways, and while it's not really a problem here, the compiler can generate different code for main than if it was named something else. In particular `main` can be only called once in C++, so a compiler could ignore the thread_local attribute or not bother with a guard variable.

Comment: Oh, true. That's definitely a bad idea now that you mention it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `fs` segment base is the address of thread-local storage (on x86-64 Linux at least).

`.zero 8` reserves 8 bytes of zeros (presumably in the BSS).  Check the GAS manual: https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/Zero.html, links in https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info.

`@tpoff` presumably means to address it relative to thread-local storage, probably stands for thread something offset, I don't know.

---

The rest of it looks similar to what gcc normally does for `static` local variables that need a runtime initializer: a guard variable that it checks every time it enters the function, falling through in the already-initialized case.

**The 1-byte guard variable is in thread-local storage.  The actual `_` itself is optimized away because it's never read.**  Notice there's no store of `eax` after `foo` returns.

BTW, `_` is a weird (bad) choice for a variable name.  Easy to miss it, and probably reserved for use by the implementation.

---

It has a nice optimization here: normally (for non-thread-local `static int var = foo();`) if it finds the guard variable isn't already initialized, it needs a thread-safe way to make sure only one thread actually does the initialization (essentially taking a lock).

But here each thread has its own guard variable (and *should* run `foo()` the first time regardless of what other threads are doing) so it doesn't need to call a `run_once` function to get mutual exclusion.

(sorry for the short answer, I may expand this later with an example on https://godbolt.org/ of a non-thread-local `static` local variable.  Or find an SO Q&A about it.)

Comment: What variable name would you use for a variable that's not used for anything except to run an initialization function once per thread?

Comment: @Artikash: Something like `dummy` would work, or document the purpose with a name like `run_once_per_thread` for that use case.  I had been assuming that your real code used it, and also that this wasn't in `main`.  The C++ standard says it's undefined behaviour to call `main` from within the program, so the implementation can put things in `main` that need to only run once at program startup.  Starting new threads with `main` as their entry point is UB, I think.

Comment: My real code uses ```_``` although not in main. MSVC implementation of ```std::terminate``` has a separate terminate handler for each thread, so I have ```thread_local static auto _ = std::set_terminate(my_terminate);``` in a function that gets run in each thread. Currently not sure whether I wanna change it to ```thread_initializer_dummy```, I originally felt like keeping to the javascript convention of unused stuff being ```_```.

Comment: @Artikash: I don't see the point of using a static local for something that every thread always needs to call.  Can't you just call it normally near the start of a function that only runs once per thread anyway so the guard isn't needed?  e.g. the function you pass to `std::thread`.  Then if you don't need the result, don't assign it to anything.

Comment: @Artikash: you have to start each thread somehow.  Is it not under your control what they do before joining the pool?  This function will only get run once per actual thread, not once per work unit dispatched to the thread pool; I hope that's what you want.  Anyway, the overhead is low, so you're fine as long as the function containing this isn't in your hottest of hot loops.  It does touch an extra cache line of memory, though.